# Looping through two dropdown selections to populate textboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to create a form and I am not 100% sure what I need to do... actually no... I am flat out stuck. So I have an array. (sample below) and I have two options that I want the user to select. Drop box one, the user will be able to select one of five categories and then from that selection only the options from that category will be available for the user to select in drop-down box two. From there it will auto populate the corresponding text boxes.

So for example if the user selects "Option three of Five Categories" then in drop down two the user will only have Option 11, Option 12, Option 13, and Option 14 available. Then if the user selects Option 13 the accompanying rest of information will display in the following four text boxes

I hope I am not too confusing and can be helped :( thanks a lot.

```
var programs = new Array();
programs[0] = ["Option One of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 1","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[1] = ["Option One of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 2","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[2] = ["Option One of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 3","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[3] = ["Option One of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 4","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[4] = ["Option Two of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 5","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[5] = ["Option Two of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 6","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[6] = ["Option Two of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 7","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[7] = ["Option Two of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 8","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[8] = ["Option Two of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 9","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[9] = ["Option Three of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 10","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[10] = ["Option Three of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 11","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[11] = ["Option Three of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 12","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[12] = ["Option Three of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 13","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[13] = ["Option Three of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 14","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[14] = ["Option Four of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 15","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[15] = ["Option Four of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 16","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[16] = ["Option Four of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 17","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[17] = ["Option Four of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 18","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[18] = ["Option Four of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 19","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[19] = ["Option Five of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 20","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[20] = ["Option Five of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 21","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[21] = ["Option Five of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 21","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[22] = ["Option Five of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 22","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
programs[23] = ["Option Five of Five Categories","Random information to display in text box one","Random information to display in text box two","Option 24","Random information to display in text box three","Random information to display in text box four"];
```

Comment: So the content of the drop-box two should depend on what the user chose in drop-box one?

Answer (score 1):

Below i have provided you code for your need but i do't wanted hard coded vale so i have created array dynamically. And also the way you are creating your is also not a preferred way Still if you want a code that follow array formate exactly like you tell me in comments.

```html
<select id="drop1" onchange="changeValueDrop2()">
</select>

<br><br><br>

<select id="drop2">

</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
 var obj=[];
 
 
 function changeValueDrop2(){
  
  var parentval=$('#drop1').val();
  $('#drop2').empty();
  
  for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
   var bean=obj[i];
   
   if(parentval==bean.parentid){
    $('#drop2').append('<option value="'+bean.dd2_text+'">parentid : '+bean.dd2_text+'</option>');
   }
  }
 
 }
 
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("Hellosss");
  
  for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
   $('#drop1').append('<option value="'+i+'">parent '+i+'</option>');
   for(b=1;b<=10;b++)
   {
    var bean ={
     dd2_text : 'parentid : '+i +', childid : '+((i)*10+b),
     parentid : i,
    }
    obj.push(bean);
   }
  }
  
  changeValueDrop2();
  console.log(obj);
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you so so much for taking the time to help me. This is a good start but unfortunately this is not exactly what I had in mind. as you said and what I saw this creates the data dynamically. I need it to pull the data from the array. Secondly I need it to populate four text boxes with the rest of the information in the row. Also if it is not an issue how would I be able to do this in javascript as opposed to jquery? Once again though thank you so so so much because I really dont know who to do this.

Comment: So you just want to use javaScript and also you want to populate 4 Dropdown and that is also just from array not array within array? IS that correct.

Comment: [drop down one] 5 Categories based on the Array

[drop down two] Select option based on category selected from the first dropdown box

[text box 1] auto populates  information from the row in the array

[text box 2] auto populates  information from the row in the array

[text box 3] auto populates  information from the row in the array

[text box 4] auto populates  information from the row in the array


I hope that makes it more clear. Thanks again!